# Where to ask question about database normalization

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking to ask a question about the creation and population of a database using C#. For example:

> I have a table for RangedItems, Charms, Necklaces, and WristItems. Now, there's an item that can go into any of those slots. What table do you add that item to?

What site is the best to ask these types of questions? This would probably also translate into a class creation question, as I would have a class for each table.

Comment: Is that the full text of the question? That doesn't look to me like it provides nearly enough information for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Added a better example.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks That would still be a pretty bad question. Anyway, what you're really asking is where to ask questions about database normalization.

Comment: If it's a sufficiently complex DB schema design question it may belong on DBA, else probably programmers.  Note that your example question is more of a "how should I design a DB schema that accomplishes this task" rather than just general best practices, which is what your title here implies.  General best practices would be too broad pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @Servy SO has a lot of these kinds of normalization questions. (1.2k under the normalization tag). I'm not sure whether they're considered off-topic though...

Comment: @Mansfield It's probably not the best place, even if it's not off topic.  I wouldn't direct anyone there, but I may not close the question if a question was posted there anyway.

Comment: @Mansfield [so] also has lots of questions that actually belong on [cs.se], [programmers.se], [cstheory.se], [crypto.se], [codereview.se], etc. but that doesn't mean that enough people with enough rep to vote that know where the question actually belongs typically sees these types of questions, and it's usually just accompanied by a (upvoted) comment, not votes.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks why don't you write out your actual question here and let people tell you more accurately if it fits one of the Stack sites? Then you can simply copy/pasta your question into the relevant Stack site, or if no Stack site is suitable paste it in a forum somewhere.